# Can i Stop the power automate flow using power apps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate, power-platform

I am working on one application their i need if user click on cancel button then status of share point list column changed to cancel. also the approval trigger associated with that item is also cancel.

- I am able to update column after clicking in the button and i don't know how to stop flow associated with that item.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge，you can not stop the power automate flow using power apps.